# How to pass variable that randomly generate to another page

Tags: php, variables, session

How can I get the `$a` in page2 as the same value 
or do I have to use the form submit?

page1

```
<?php
session_start();
function random()
{
    $rand = rand(1000,2000);
    return $rand;
}
$a = random();
echo $a;
?>
```

page2

```
<?php
session_start();
$b =$_SESSION[$a];
echo $b;
?>
```

Comment: Store it in the session

Comment: You do nothing with `$a` other than echo it... on `page2` there is no session variable set so `$b =$_SESSION[$a];` makes no sense. On the first page set the value from `random` in a session variable

Comment: NB: The PHP close tag (`?>`) is usually unneeded, and can cause some unwanted chars to be written in the output buffer.

Answer (score 4):

In page 1 you forgot to store the value in the session.

$a exist only in page 1 execution and its stop to exist at the end of the execution

To store the value in the session, beside session_start(), you need to valorize it in the session array with a specific key, let's say "my_random_number"

page 1 add:

```
$a = random();
echo $a;
$_SESSION['my_random_number'] = $a;
```

In page 2 change $b =$_SESSION[$a]; in

```
$b =$_SESSION['my_random_number'];
```

Comment: I also recommend to serialize the session like $_SESSION['random_string'] = serialize($a); on page 1 and the unserialize it page 2 like this $b = unserialize($_SESSION['random_string']

Comment: Why do you need to serialize the value? The whole session is already serialized, it is just an overhead.